# Find value of unending continued fraction

Tags: limits, continued-fractions

I am trying to find the limit if it exists for the following unending continued fraction: $$1+{1\over{2+{1\over2+{1\over{2+...}}}}}$$

I have discovered this is the continued fraction for $\sqrt2$, but I am unsure how to show this.

Also I am being asked to assume that the even-order and odd-order truncations have a limit as well and calculate each of them.  How would I go about finding any of these limits?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = 2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dots}}}$.  Then \begin{align*} 
x - 2 &= \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dots}}} \\
\frac{1}{x-2} &= 2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dots}}} \\
\frac{1}{x-2} &= x
\end{align*}
We find two roots to this quadratic equation, $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$.  Since $x = 2+\dots > 2$, we ignore the negative root and continue with $x = 1+\sqrt{2}$.  The number you have is therefore $$1+\frac{1}{x} = 1 + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} = 1+\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{1-2} = 1+\sqrt{2}-1 = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Nice solution, which presumes that the limit exists.

Comment: Can't we assume this because we can construct a monotonic and bounded sequence which must converge to this?

Answer (score 2):

Neglecting the 1 that's added in the beginning, you can find the value of the continued fraction by solving the equation $x = \frac{1}{2 + x}$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add $1$ to the original continued fraction and get that $x = 2 + \frac{1}{x}$. Still leads to the same solution though.